# Garage door chain sagging on one side

Tags: garage

My garage door opens ok but the chain sags on one side and slaps on the door when opening.  The other side is tight.  Is it not tight enough?  I don't want to bust it by over tightening.
Thank you

Comment: I would recommend getting a garage door repair person. If you make a mistook you can injure yourself. The reason: Over 20,000 garage door repair related injuries are reported every year. This includes over 7,000 pinching injuries (which can result in finger amputations), more than 2,000 crushing injuries (caused by a falling garage door), and 800 lacerations (from the glass in garage windows).

Comment: Sounds like you are talking about the opener , not the door ?

Comment: It does sound slightly loose, but one side being tight is normal for _any_ chain. That's where the load is. Don't over-tighten or you'll wreck the motor shaft bearings.

Comment: Please do not use the box labeled "Answer" to say "Thank you" - if you'll take the [tour], you'll note that the proper way to say "thanks" is to click the up-arrow next to any answer that you find helpful, and to click the check-mark next to the one that helps the most. Also, you appear to have 2 accounts now, you can [click here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for instructions on how to get them merged.

Answer (score 3):

If you check the installation manual for your specific opener, you'll likely find the process for adjusting the chain tension. I've recently installed a belt drive opener in which the manual included those instructions. In the case of my system, the door is to be disconnected (using the release handle), removing spring tension from the equation. The carriage is moved to the location specified in the manual and the mid-point sag is measured and adjusted to match the manual's specifications.

If you follow those specifications, you will not damage it, because you won't be over-tightening it.